# How to append string in java script with pre increment in same line

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I have 1 variable contains `int` value and one having `String`. Now I want to append the string like pre-increment the int variable like below code I am getting error

```
var count = 0;
var message = "value of Variable Count by increment  is:"+ ++count;
```

Comment: `(++count)`  add brackets

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your counter with brackets like `(++count)`

```
var count = 0;
var message = "value of Variable Count by increment  is:" + (++count);
console.log(message);
```

```js
var count = 0;
var message = "value of Variable Count by increment  is:"+ (++count);
console.log(message);
console.log("value of Variable Count by increment  is:"+ (++count));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Number` as a standard function:

```
var count = 0;
var message = "value of Variable Count by increment  is:"+ Number(++count);
console.log(message);
```